# Application of derivatives, proof check.

Tags: derivatives

[image]

**Part a)**

I know answer is the second one, because S is a function of three variables and therefore partial derivatives are taken, and further x,y,z are functions of t only, so total derivative is taken.

Is there any better explanation for this?

**Part b)**

$S=2(xy+yz+zx)$

$\frac{ds}{dt}= 2\left(x\frac{dy}{dt}+y\frac{dx}{dt} +y\frac{dz}{dt}+z\frac{dy}{dt}+z\frac{dx}{dt}+x\frac{dz}{dt}\right)$

Is it fine ?

Comment: What you did seems all correct to me. I think you only made a computation mistake

Comment: Computation mistake, where ?

Comment: And is there a better explanation for part a?

Comment: the computation in part b)

Comment: I think it is fine, If you have found any mistake please tell me.

Comment: The answer 17.5 is wrong. That is what is meant when I said computing error.

Comment: Oh that is fyn, that I know.